# Win32: How to multiplex all events in 1 thread

Tags: windows, sockets, user-interface, winapi, events

I know that I need to use GetMessage to wait for GUI events but let's say I want to also wait for socket events (network incoming datas) or console events (stdin incoming datas) in the same thread. For example in Linux, you know that it's easy to wait for socket events and stdin events in just 1 thread with epoll or select.

I'm reading the Microsoft documentation and I don't understand how to multiplex events. Am I obliged to use a thread pool ?

Comment: you can patially use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` which let wait for gui events, another waitable objects and accept apc. but for handle iocp packets anyway need separate thread [pool]

Comment: Ok so I have to create 1 thread for iocp and 1 thread for messages ?

Comment: depend from your tasks. for handle iocp usual we create not single thread but pool of threads. also not mandatory do this yourself. let if we call `BindIoCompletionCallback` - system do all task yourself

Comment: Sadly, I can't find any official tutorial for iocp. It's very hard. Thanks anyway

Comment: The main thing to keep in mind with IOCP is that the OVERLAPPED pointer you submit with the call that starts the IO operation is the same pointer you get back from GetQueuedCompletionResult. This means that you can extend the OVERLAPPED structure (either via C++-style inheritance or C-style containment) with data custom to your needs. The IO sub-system deals with the OVERLAPPED members in-place rather than copying them to an internal buffer.

Comment: For sockets, you can use [`WSAAsyncSelect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaasyncselect) to receive socket notifications via window messages, thus playing nice with your `GetMessage()` loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - *The WSAAsyncSelect function automatically sets socket s to nonblocking mode* - this suggests a definite and ineffective programming model for socket. think use `WSAAsyncSelect` very bad choice. good only asynchronous model and iocp. of course is option based

Comment: @RbMm that is your opinion. Even non-blocking sockets can be used effectively when used properly. IOCP is not always the best answer for all situations

Comment: A more efficient way is using [WSPEventSelect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/event-object-signaling-2) and [WSPEnumNetworkEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742275%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (instead of WSAAsyncSelect) along with [PeekMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea) (instead of GetMessage). Refer to [Windows Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/windows-messages-2)

Comment: Thanks for all your responses ! I understood that I can use iocp to get sockets and file events but can I use it to get console events or gui events ?

Comment: @daiSKeul Use pipe redirect the console data to your thread. Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output). Do you mind sharing why you need handle all types (network/console/windows message) of event/data in one thread?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Yes it's because I really appreciate the linux's epoll technology and I wanted to know if it was possible to get the same result with Windows API technologies

Comment: @daiSKeul Hi, sorry for late. I get confirmation that Windows don't support multiplex all events in a single thread. A workaround is discussed in above comments, convert network events to message and redirect the console data to the thread.